# Unexpected results from SELECT FROM WHERE X NOT IN Y

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

So...

```
select COUNT(*) cnt from docDocument d 
inner join tblAttachment a on d.AttachmentID = a.ID
where
a.ContainerID = 1
```

Returns 6673

```
select COUNT(*) from tblAttachment 
where 
ContainerID = 1
```

Returns 10372

```
select COUNT(*) cnt from docDocument d 
right join tblAttachment a on d.AttachmentID = a.ID
where
a.ContainerID = 1 
AND
d.ID IS NULL
```

Returns 3699 which makes sense as 10372 - 6673 = 3699

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
select ID from tblAttachment a
where 
a.ContainerID = 1
Except
(
    SELECT AttachmentId from docDocument 
)
) tst
```

Unsurprisingly returns 3699... However...

```
select COUNT(*) from tblAttachment a
where 
a.ContainerID = 1 AND
a.ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT d.AttachmentId from docDocument  d
)
```

I was expecting this to return 3699 but surprisingly it's returning 0.

Can anyone explain these results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the subquery returns a null value, the `NOT IN` is no longer true, and no rows are returned.

Either aviod null values to be returned:

```
select COUNT(*) from tblAttachment a
where 
a.ContainerID = 1 AND
a.ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT d.AttachmentId from docDocument  d WHERE d.AttachmentId IS NOT NULL
)
```

Or switch to the "null safe" `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select COUNT(*) from tblAttachment a
where 
a.ContainerID = 1 AND
NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * from docDocument  d WHERE d.AttachmentId =  a.ID
)
```

Comment: Thanks WHERE d.AttachmentId IS NOT NULL did the trick.  I should have thought of that NULL values have bitten me many times before

Comment: You're not alone. I've learned to always do NOT EXISTS instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your not in query return nulls value. So its displaying zero records.

This is the below scenario you are getting right now. Let's try to understand that and make the changes.

```
select * 
into #tab1 
from (select 'a' Name union all
      select 'b'union all
      select 'c'union all
      select 'd'union all
      select 'e') AS A

select * 
into #tab2 
from (select 'd' Name union all
      select 'e' union all
      select NULL) AS A
```

**Not Exists**

```
select Name 
from #tab1  
where not exists (select * 
                  from #tab2 
                  where #tab1.Name = #tab2.Name )
```

**Left Join**

```
select t1.Name 
from #tab1 t1
left join #tab2 t2 on t1.Name = t2.Name 
where t2.Name is null
```

**Not in**

```
select * 
from #tab1 
where Name not in (select Name from #tab2)
```

**Note:** whenever a `Not` in query returns `NULL`, the outer query returns blank data.

Answer (score 1):

**You must be having NULL values in docDocument table...That's why you are not getting anything.**

Please try like this **USE NOT EXISTS**

```
select COUNT(*) from tblAttachment a
where 
a.ContainerID = 1 AND
NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT d.AttachmentId from docDocument  d
    WHERE a.ID = d.ID
)
```

**You can use EXCEPT operator.**

```
select * into #tab1 from (
select 'a' Name union all
select 'b'union all
select 'c'union all
select 'd'union all
select 'e'

)AS A

select * into #tab2 from 
(
select 'd' Name union all
select 'e' union all
select NULL
)AS A
```

**SOLUTION**

select Name from #tab1
EXCEPT
select * from #tab2

OUTPUT

```
Name
----
a
b
c

(3 rows affected)
```

Comment: This also returns 0, for the same reason as in the above answer

Comment: Please check again.  I am joining on ID column which will not be NULL. You are joining on column which can be NULL so you will get nothing. Otherwise you can use EXCEPT. select Name from #tab1  
EXCEPT
select * from #tab2